# How to get id of an image tag which is created dynamically..?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Here while clicking the delete button i need to get the present ID of the image button.How to get id  of an image tag which is created    dynamically using jquery

```
var deleteButton = document.createElement("img");
deleteButton.setAttribute("style", "height:20px;width:20px;float:right;padding-right:5px");
deleteButton.setAttribute("class", "btnposition");
deleteButton.setAttribute("id", "deleteButton" + _SerialNumber);
var onclickMethod1 = "DeleteBillDetails('billDetailsWrap','wholeInsideId'," + _SerialNumber +")";
deleteButton.setAttribute("onclick", onclickMethod1);
deleteButton.src = "../../Images/Delete.png";
packingRow1.appendChild(deleteButton);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Remove the onclick method from your control and use below methods to write your logic.You can get the ID in this way easily

```
$(document).on('click','.btnPosition',function(){
    var id= $(this).prop('id');
    // Write your logic here 
})
```

OR

```
$('.btnPosition').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    // Write your logic here 
})
```

Comment: I done like you told, But I am getting an error which says value undefined. Can you please help...

Comment: are you able to debug the script and if yes did it hit the method??